# C# data structure to add elements in order

Tags: c#, .net, sorting, data-structures

I am looking for a data structure in C# (.net framework) which I can use to add data in sorted order (instead of adding all data and then applying sort). My data are objects and I want to add them according to a certain field (integer field).

Thanks

Comment: Have you thought about adding the data to a List<string> and call Sort() method prior to adding the values..? also give an example of what type of data you are wanting to add.. is the data coming from a Table, File, List, etc...????

Answer (score 9, accepted):

option 1) use the [SortedList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.sortedlist.aspx) and use your integer fields as key.

option 2) use [SortedSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412070.aspx) but be cautious .. this collection can only contain unique objects (no duplicates of the same object)

Answer (score 1):

```
[System.Collections.Generic.SortedSet<T>][1]
```